# Проверка кеш файла и выполнение условия

Tags: php, кэширование

```
<?php
$id_kp = 'xxx';
$id = 'xxx';
$token='xxx';
$cache_time = 5;

$cache_eps = "cache/$id_kp-eps.txt";
$cache_date = "cache/$id_kp-date.txt";

$servername="localhost";
$username="serial";
$password="serial";
$dbname="serial";

//  Запрос 1
    $json=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://moonwalk.cc/api/videos.json?kinopoisk_id=$id_kp&api_token=$token"));
    foreach($json as $item){
    $dates[]=$item->last_episode_time;}
    rsort($dates);
    $date=array_shift($dates);
    file_put_contents($cache_date,$date);

// Запрос 2
    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if(!$conn){ die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());}
    $sql="UPDATE dle_post SET date='$date' WHERE id=$id";if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){echo "good";}else {echo "bad";}
    mysqli_close($conn);

// Запрос 3
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://moonwalk.cc/api/videos.json?kinopoisk_id=$id_kp&api_token=$token"));
    foreach($json as $item) {
    $translator = $item->translator;
    $translator_id = $item->translator_id;
    $szneps = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://moonwalk.cc/api/serial_episodes.json?kinopoisk_id=$id_kp&translator_id=$translator_id&api_token=$token"));

    foreach($szneps->season_episodes_count as $item){
    $szn[]=$item->season_number;
    $eps[]=$item->episodes_count;
    }
    rsort($szn);
    $sezon=array_shift($szn);
    sort($eps);
    $episodes=array_shift($eps);
    $ftrs = $translator . ' • s';
    $fszn = $sezon . 'e';
    $feps = $episodes . ', ';
    $treps[] = $ftrs . $fszn . $feps;
    file_put_contents($cache_eps, $treps);
}



  if (file_exists($cache_date)) {

    if ((time() - $cache_time) < filemtime($cache_date)) { echo 'time good';} 
    else    {
    //************** 
    // Если кеш УСТАРЕЛ выполняем запрос 1
    //**************
    echo 'time bad, update';
            }

    } else {
    //**************
    // Если кеша НЕТ выполняем запрос 1
    //**************
    echo 'no cashe, create file';
           }

    // Как вот здесь, создать условие если кеш есть и соответствует переменной $date
    // то НЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕМ запрос, если же он отличается от переменной $date то ВЫПОЛНЯЕМ ЗАПРОС 2

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// дата из файла $cache_date, чтобы сравнить с $date
$last_cache_date = file_get_contents($cache_date);

// условие если кеш есть
file_exists($cache_date){

  // кеш есть и соответствует переменной $date
  // это не правильное условие, не знаю что вы имели ввиду
  if($last_cache_date == $date)
    // НЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕМ запрос
  }
  else {
    // ВЫПОЛНЯЕМ ЗАПРОС 2
  }
}
```

надеюсь правильно понял значение "создать условие если кеш есть и соответствует переменной $date"